# Functions and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

The question is

Design the grade processing program to use functions and an array. Let user enter number of grades (set the maximum to 50). Store grades in an array. Create a separate function for each calculation (total of 3 functions): 1) average grade, 2) maximum grade, 3) number of grades above the average.   Display all results.

I think I got the main part, but I'm having trouble with how to write the functions, the functions are outputting one for some reason, and I'm having trouble writing the max function or how to start it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double average(double x[], int n);
double maximum(double x[], int n);
int nAboveAvg(double x[], int n);

int main()
{
    double grades[50];
    int ngrades;

    cout<<"How many grades? (max = 50)";
    cin>>ngrades;

//create for loop to get grades from user
    for(int i = 0; i<ngrades; i++)
    {
         cout<<"Enter grade ";
         cin>> grades[i];
    }

      //call the functions
   double avg = average(grades, ngrades);
   double max = maximum(grades, ngrades);
   int nAbove = nAboveAvg(grades, ngrades);
   //display results

   cout<<"Average = "<<avg<<endl;
   cout<<"# above average = "<<nAbove<<endl;


}

double average(double x[], int npts) //define the functon to recieve the array
{
    double sum = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k<npts; k++)
    {
       sum = sum +x[k];
    }
    return sum / npts;
}
double maximum(double x[], int npts)
{
   double max = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<npts; i++)
   {
      if(max == npts)
      {
          return max;
      }
      if(max < npts)
      {
          return npts;
      }
   }
}
int nAboveAvg(double x[], int npts)
{
    int nAboveAvg = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<npts;i++)
    {
        if(x[i] > npts)
        {
            nAboveAvg++;
        }
    }
    return nAboveAvg;
}
```

Comment: What sort of trouble, specifically?

Comment: I having trouble with the functions, its not printing out the right output

Answer (score 2):

## Incorrect Printing

```
//call the functions
double avg = average(grades, ngrades);
double max = maximum(grades, ngrades);
int nAbove = nAboveAvg(grades, ngrades);
```

Notice that you define variables named `avg` and `nAbove`.

```
//display results
cout<<"Average = "<<average<<endl;
cout<<"# above average = "<<nAboveAvg<<endl;
```

But then you use `average` and `nAboveAvg` (the functions) when you attempt to print the results.

The correct version here would be:

```
cout << "Average = " << avg << endl;
cout << "# above average = " << nAbove << endl;
```

---

## Compiler Warnings

When I try to [compile this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51ab294bfdb13018), the compiler emits a number of warnings. e.g.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:29:24: warning: the address of 'double average(double*, int)' will always evaluate as 'true' [-Waddress]

    cout<<"Average = "<<average<<endl;
```

or

```
main.cpp:24:11: warning: unused variable 'avg' [-Wunused-variable]

    double avg = average(grades, ngrades);
```

It is a good idea not to ignore those warnings.

---

## Count Above Average

```
        if(x[i] > npts)
        {
            nAboveAvg++;
        }
```

You compare the *value at position **i*** with *number of input values*.
However, you should be comparing *value at position **i*** with *the average of all the values*. Hence

```
int nAboveAvg(double x[], int npts)
{
    int count = 0;
    double avg = average(x, npts);

    for (int i(0); i < npts; ++i) {
        if (x[i] > avg) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

### Refactoring

You may now notice that in our program we end up calculating the average value twice. We can fix this by making our function more general -- instead of counting number of values above average, let's count the number of values above arbitrary target passed as a parameter.

```
int count_above(double x[], int npts, double target)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i(0); i < npts; ++i) {
        if (x[i] > target) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now we can write

```
//call the functions
double avg = average(grades, ngrades);
double max = maximum(grades, ngrades);
int nAbove = count_above(grades, ngrades, avg);
```

---

## Maximum Value

Let's think about the algorithm, and start from simplest case -- only one value in the array. In this scenario the first value is also the maximum.

```
double max = x[0];
```

Knowing that, let's consider how to find the maximum when there are 2 values in the input array. We already know the maximum of all the values before the second value. Therefore

```
if (x[1] > max) {
    max = x[1];
}
```

Next step, input array with 3 values. Again, we already know the maximum of all the values before the third value. Therefore

```
if (x[2] > max) {
    max = x[2];
}
```

We can see a pattern repeating here, which we can wrap in a loop.

```
double maximum(double x[], int npts)
{
    if (npts <= 0) {
        exit(-1); // Error...
    }

    double max = x[0];

    for (int i(1); i < npts; ++i) {
        if (x[i] > max) {
            max = x[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

---

## Validating Input

You don't have any validation of the input passed to your functions, yet there are some obvious cases that need to be accounted for.

- In all of your functions, what should happen when the `npts` is negative?
- What's the average value of a 0 elements?
- What's the maximum value of 0 elements?

A very simple way to handle those cases would be to return some special value as a result. You then have to check the results for this value every time you call the function. In many cases it may be hard to select an appropriate value for this.

Another possibility that would be accepted at a beginner level, would be simply printing some error message to console, and exiting the program. For example

```
if (npts <= 0) {
    cerr << "Too few values in input array." << endl;
    exit(-1); // Error...
}
```

The proper C++ approach would be to **throw an exception**, for example [std::invalid_argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument). For example

```
#include <stdexcept>

// ....

if (npts <= 0) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Too few values in input array.);
}
```

Comment: oh ok I see now I wasn't printing out the values, that makes sense now, how would you write the max function then

Comment: @user2969508 Think about how you would find the maximum value if you had only 1 element. Knowing how to solve that, how would you continue if there were 2 elements? Knowing that (the maximum of first two elements), what would be the next step if there were 3 elements?

Comment: @user2969508 Additionally, you should add some error checking to your functions. For example, in `average`, what will happen in `return sum / npts;` in case `npts == 0` ?

Comment: will if that was the case, it would be undefined because you cant divide by zero

Comment: Exactly, so you should probably check for such case in the beginning of the function and handle it appropriately -- throw an exception, return some error code, or maybe even exiting the program would be acceptable at this level. Have a shot at fixing the code and writing your implementation of the `maximum` function. Post the new revision in your question and let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Also it is not printing out the amount of numbers above the average

Comment: Yes, I see. I will update the answer. As Bill Dhimitri mentions, the test `x[i] > npts` does not make sense. You don't want to compare the values with the total count, but with average. Hence, first in the function, you should find out the average (calling your existing function), and then compare each value against the result it returned.

Comment: @ Dan Mašek So I know in order to get the average I need to call the function Average into nAboveAverage, how would I do that then?

Comment: Dan Mašek oh I see that makes sense, that how you call a function, thanks. I'm still having trouble with the max value though

Comment: @user2969508 Yes, it's the thing as you did in the block labeled with `//call the functions`. I added the explanation of the algorithm for finding the maximum. One more thing came to mind regarding the `nAboveAvg` -- you may notice that now we calculate the average twice. We can refactor the code a little and write a more general function. I'll add details in the answer.

Comment: @user2969508 Hopefully that clears everything up. Let me know if there's anything else. If you're happy with this, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "average" function looks good.  In the last 2 lines in main, I think you want to output avg instead of average (because average is the name of the function, not the name of the variable that holds the computed value).  Similarly, output nAbove instead of nAboveAvg.

The maximum function looks like an empty implementation.  I don't think that will compile because it needs to (at least) return a double value.

In the nAboveAvg function, "x[i] > npts" seems like the wrong test.  I think you want to compare x[i] to avg (you will want to pass avg into this function as an argument.

Comment: Yeah I'm having trouble with writing the max function so I left it blank for now and thanks